# Hubspot API Not Recognizing State/ Region Attribute

Tags: hubspot-api

I am trying to set the **State/Region** when creating a contact via the REST API. All the other fields are populated except for **State/Region**.

**What is the correct name of this attribute?**

Here is the post:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://fbamembers.com/hubspot-contact/$ownerkey' --form 'first-name="Joe"' --form 'last-name="Smith"' --form 'email="js@gmail.com"' --form 'phone="1234567890"'--form 'state-region="NY"' --form 'liquid-capital="60000"'
```

Here is the response:

```
{"success":true}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: state-region="NY"
```

Comment: https://fbamembers.com/hubspot-contact/aTFzWnJ2dTl0Y20WejRYTjAWTTBCaU343T09333 -> 404 "Broker form was not found"

Comment: make sure your example is reproducible

Comment: @mark  it is reproducible but I changed the part of the URL that identified my instance of HubSpot so that 1,000 people would not create test contacts in my account.   I changed the example to make this more clear.